# PHP PDO returns true

Tags: php, postgresql, heroku, pdo, heroku-postgres

I'm trying to pull out some data from my database, but a boolean is returned (as expected), but then when I try the variations of `->fetch()`, I get the error `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on bool`.

Somehow, it seems like the `->execute();`-function saves the bool rather than the object - I'm not sure why. I think I've stared myself blind on my code?

### Code

```php
<?php
$cc = $pdo->prepare("SELECT country FROM quarter WHERE company_id = ? GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY country ASC")->execute([$_GET["id"]]);
#var_dump($cc);
var_dump($cc->fetch());
var_dump($cc->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN));
?>
```

### Expected response

```
country
GB
NO
```

### Actual response

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on bool in [..]
```

Comment: Share the complete code along with the table too.

Comment: you can't chain PDO::prepare and PDOStatement::execute here as PDOStatement::execute returns a boolean, not the original PDOStatement obtained from prepare. So the fetch apply on a boolean, the result of PDOStatement::execute, not a PDOStatement instance. You have to split prepare and execute in 2 instructions.

Comment: @julp Seems like unchaining it worked. As I said, I stared myself blind on my code... Will you post an answer so that I can award you the pnts? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `execute()` method [returns](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.execute.php) bool while `prepare()` [returns](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepare.php) object

You should use `fetch()` method of the object itself

```
$cc = $pdo->prepare("SELECT country FROM quarter WHERE company_id = ? GROUP BY 1 ORDER BY country ASC");

$cc->execute([$_GET["id"]]);
#var_dump($cc);
var_dump($cc->fetch());
```